# "Can not find module" error message is appearing in browser console

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm new at Angular CLI. I ran following lines at root of Angular project.

```
issue-management\src\webui>ng generate module pages\dashboard
issue-management\src\webui>ng generate component pages\dashboard
```

but "moduleName-routing.module.ts" files didn't generate, created them manually. I tried to create a module with "--routing" parameter but result didn't change. Same error message appeared in browser. Folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

dashboard-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

dashboard.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
      {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
      {path: 'issue', loadChildren: './pages/issue/issue.module#IssueModule'},
      {path: 'project', loadChildren: './pages/project/project.module#ProjectModule'}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Following error message is showing in browser console.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module'
Error: Cannot find module './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try loading the children with `import` promise as following:

```
...

{
   path: 'dashboard', 
   loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
},

...
```